# Multiple bindings on same domain in IIS to subfolders

Tags: iis

I have multiple domains, such as:

```
abc.example.com
bcd.example.com
cde.example.com
```

And a root directory:

```
D:\websites\example.com
```

I want to point each to its own directory, as in:

```
D:\websites\example.com\abc
D:\websites\example.com\bcd
D:\websites\example.com\cde
```

I can obviously do this manually by setting each one up as a separate website. But is there a way to do this in some sort of wildcard fashion, so I can add more domains as necessary, create a subfolder, and have it setup automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"But is there a way to do this in some sort of wildcard fashion". No, there isn't.

If you don't want to manually create all those sites, write some PowerShell scripts to automate the steps.